The user id is getting null here
I am trying to retrieve id and I am using jwt token, but id is null.
This is my code where I am getting the error:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpPost("BookDoctor")]
public async Task<IActionResult> BookDoctor(PatientAppointmentDto model)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var isAvailable =await appoinmentService.CheckAvailability(model.DoctorId, model.Date, model.TimeStart);

        if (!isAvailable)
        {
            return BadRequest("Doctor not available");
        }

        model.TimeEnd = model.TimeStart.AddMinutes(30);
        var currentUser = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        
        await appoinmentService.AddAsync(model.Info,
            model.Date, model.TimeStart, model.TimeEnd,
            model.DoctorId, currentUser.ToString());
        
        return Ok(model.Id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}

The user id I get is null.
This my method to generate the token:
private async Task<JwtSecurityToken> CreateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    var roleClaims = new List<Claim>();

    foreach (var role in roles)
        roleClaims.Add(new Claim("roles", role));

    var claims = new[]
           {
               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Name),
               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id) // User ID
           }
           .Union(userClaims)
           .Union(roleClaims);

    var Key = _IConfiguration["JWT:key"];
    var issuer = _IConfiguration["JWT:issuer"];
    var audience = _IConfiguration["JWT:Audience"];
    var dur = _IConfiguration["JWT:DurationInDays"];
    var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key));
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
               issuer: issuer,
               audience: audience,
               claims: claims,
               expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(double.Parse(dur)),
               signingCredentials: signingCredentials);
}

And this is my program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(option =>
{
    option.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    option.SaveToken = false;
    option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"]))
    };
});
           return jwtSecurityToken;
       }

I am trying to retrieve the id but I only get null.
var currentUser = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

Can anyone help me regarding this code I am using jwt token for authentication passing joken to use this endpoint.

ASP.NET Core 6 is out of support. The oldest supported ASP.NET Core version is 8. There's no reason to use an old version for a new project

@PanagiotisKanavos i am using version 8

Your NameIdentifier and Sub may be crossed. This may help, but not sure, try adding NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier inside your TokenValidationParameters in Program.cs.
